# iOS - can only hit html button once

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, iphone

I created a [soundboard](http://www.kraeuterelfe.de/neueSeite/hermann/) page from a popular funny german farmer, with alot of buttons. I noticed that my brother is unable to push a button more than once on his apple smartphone (iphone 7). If he presses the same button again, then no sound plays. He even tried it with chrome browser, same result. On windows phone and android it works perfectly fine, same for desktop-pc.

Is this a coding bug or related to bad iOS software?

This is the relevant code.

**Button samples:**

```
<button class="button" data-mp3-file="audio/favorit03.mp3">
    Hör auf hieeer!!
</button>
<button class="button" data-mp3-file="audio/favorit12.mp3">
    Hier wirst du verrückt du!
</button>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
var allAudioFiles = [];

$(".button").each(function() {

    var audio = {};
    audio["id"] = $(this).data("mp3-file");
    audio["audioObj"] = new Audio($(this).data("mp3-file"));

    allAudioFiles.push(audio);
});

$(".button").click(function() {

    var id = $(this).data("mp3-file");
    var audio = $.grep(
        allAudioFiles, 
        function(e){ 
            return e.id === id; 
        }
    );
    var sound = audio[0].audioObj;
    sound.play();
});
```

Comment: @Taplar, sorry, I accidentially removed `sound.play();` from the code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
$(".button").click(function() {   
  document.getElementById('audioSource').src = $(this).data("mp3-file");
  var audio = document.getElementById('audio');
  audio.load();
  audio.play();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="button" data-mp3-file="http://mattersofgrey.com/audio/Minecraft-purr1.mp3">test1</button>
<button class="button" data-mp3-file="http://mattersofgrey.com/audio/Minecraft-purr2.mp3">test2</button>
<button class="button" data-mp3-file="http://mattersofgrey.com/audio/Minecraft-purr3.mp3">test3</button>
<audio id="audio">
  <source id="audioSource" src="" type="audio/mpeg"></source>
  Your browser does not support the audio format.
</audio>
```